# Defining a quotient topology based off of level sets.

Tags: general-topology

Is my understanding of the quotient topology correct?

Let $f$ be a continuous surjective mapping $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

Let $\bf x_1$ and $\bf x_2$ be $n$-tuples in $\mathbb R^n$. Say $\bf x_1 \sim \bf x_2$ if $f(\bf{x_1}$$) = f(\bf{x_2}$$)$ (ie. they lie on the same level set).

Does there exist a homeomorphism from the quotient space $\mathbb R^n /\!\!\sim$ to $\mathbb R$?

In my mind, we have that level sets or the equivalence classes are "condensed" into points on $\mathbb R$ given by the value of the particular level set. It follows that open sets $\mathbb R^n /\!\!\sim$ are given by the level curves that fit in $a < f < b$ for $a < b$.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under you assumptions, the induced map $\tilde{f}$ from the quotient to $\mathbb{R}$ sending a class $[x]$ to $f(x)$ is a well defined continuous bijection. However I believe that if you want $\tilde{f}$ to be a homeomorphism, it is sufficient for $f$ to additionally be open.

edit: replaced "necessary" by "sufficient".

Comment: Does it still hold that the open sets in the quotient topology are described by "open intervals of level sets"?

Comment: Is it clear that you require $f$ open? What about $f(x)=x^3-3x$. This is not open, since $f((-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3}))=[-2,2]$, but I can't construct an open set in $\mathbb R/\sim$ which is problematic.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have said "sufficient" instead of "necessary". I will edit the post.